# Game Center showing wrong icon for my application

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

Can you tell me where I supposed to enter name of the icon for my game, so Game Center will show my icon correctly? I guess something was messed up and now I have icon from my other app on the Game Center.

Comment: isn't that managed in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Hmm... I'm testing application with sandbox Game Center, so I guess there is no need to register it on iTunes Connect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manage the Game Center environment (both real and sandbox) at itunesconnect.apple.com. I think some of its functions don't work right if you're not using Safari.

Login with your Apple ID, choose "Manage Your Applications". That's where you upload your icon and do other things.